# copy one column value to another column in a list

Tags: list, 2007, list-view, lookup-column, out-of-the-box

I have a list named ABC in MOSS 2007

List has

1. 2 Views (All Details and Multi Location)
2. 2 columns (BA-tech and BA for both views)
3. BA- tech field is "Single line of text" type and BA field is "Look up" pointing to another list "MyList's" "Name" Column of Drop Down type
4. BA-tech column will be visible in "Multi Location" view only and BA in "All Details" view only

I want to

**Click "Edit in Datasheet" for "Multi Location" view and  input BA-tech name then BA-tech name should be populated in BA column of "All Details" View**

Note- I want to do this OOB only

Help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I really hope you already have figured out a solution as this question is a little old. Anyways if it helps what I would do to resolve it is simply use a SharePoint Designer Workflow to copy the value of the "BA Tech" column to the "BA" column.

As the BA value should be created in your other list, it's crucial to include this instruction on your Workflow. And finally add the action to copy the value to the BA column already existing on your list.

I am not writing all the steps with all the proper detail as probably you already solved the issue, but if not, let me know.